# Convolution function

Tags: scala, mathematics

I implemented the following function using the matrix object from [breeze library](https://github.com/scalanlp/breeze). Basically it is just a glorified `while` loop.

The convolution there is extremely slow so I rolled out my own, optimized on a kernel which is just a vector. This is already much faster but I figured there must be something else I can to to make this go faster.

The most expensive operation according to the profiler is the instantiation of the `ArrayDeque`  (pointed by the arrow) which I don’t really need because all I wanted was a circular buffer, but could not find much in the library.

The second thing is calling `until` on the `Int`. I don't think that can be avoided.

Boxing the doubles is also taking quite some time, maybe there is a way to specialize?

Finally the majority of the time is taken by the function call itself (circled in red) which I don’t know what it means. Any insight?

```
def conv(m: DenseMatrix[Int], k: DenseVector[Double]): DenseMatrix[Double] = {
    val kData = k.data
    val dataIter = m.data.iterator
    val height = m.rows
    val convoluted = Array.newBuilder[Double]
    val prev = mutable.ArrayDeque.empty[Double]
    for (_ <- 1 until k.length) {
      prev.addOne(dataIter.next())
    }
    var count = k.length - 1
    while (dataIter.hasNext) {
      val cur = dataIter.next()
      val slice = prev.append(cur)
      if (count % height >= k.length - 1) {
        var r = 0D
        for (i <- 0 until k.length) {
          r += kData(i) * slice(i)
        }
        convoluted.addOne(r)
      }
      prev.removeHead()
      count += 1
    }
    DenseMatrix.create(m.rows - (k.length - 1), m.cols, convoluted.result())
  }
```

Following is the annotated flamechart, *please note that `fut` is the above function `conv`.* Everything else is unchanged.

[image: flamechart]

Answer (score 2):

> all I wanted was a circular buffer

Consider using an array accessed with `mod`.

That is, assign size `s = k.length - 1`,
allocate a "previous" array `p`,
and then access `p[i % s]`.

If you're lucky, the compiler may notice that
a portion of the code is just copying,
and it will issue `memcpy` instructions.